# System cannot find JavaApplicationLauncher

Tags: java

I am running Mac OS X version 12.0.1 also known as Monterey.  I have installed the MultiWii program to control a drone I'm building.  The tutorial steps through the download, extraction and even a special chmod instruction for MacOS.  However, when I try to run the MultiWiiConf.app, the OS pops up a window with a ton of information about why it failed.  Among the information is the following statement.

> Library not loaded:
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaApplicationLauncher.framework/Versions/A/JavaApplicationLauncher

I have looked quite a bit around the internet and nobody else seems to have this problem nor any solution for it.  In attempts to fix this, I have installed and uninstalled many JDK and JRE.  This never changes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with MultiWii, though I had a similar error when trying to run another (older) Java application. I was able to get it to work by replacing the JavaApplicationStub with universalJavaApplicationStub.

In short, right-click on the application and Show Package Contents. Go to Contents/MacOS. Replace the file JavaApplicationStub with the file universalJavaApplicationStub in the src folder of the [universalJavaApplicationStub](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub) GitHub project.

The solution came from the following sources:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252335117
- https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub

Comment: had a similar issue with Logism, this worked for me, just one thing to add. You need to rename ** universalJavaApplicationStub** to **JavaApplicationStub**

Answer (score 0):

Launching Logism from the application icon doesn't work but this worked for me:

Right click on the Logism application icon then Show package Contents > contents > java > logism.jar

Double clicking on logism.jar finally launched the application for me.

I found this workournd in this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-HfWImd_0E